# How to send USDC from solana-cli command line

Tags: solana, solana-web3js, solana-cli, solana-transaction-instruction

I am trying to send USDC from the solana-cli command line but I can't find any example in the documentation. Everything is references to how to do it in javascript importing these 2 libraries.

`import * as web3 from "@solana/web3.js";`
`import * as splToken from "@solana/spl-token";`

The first to transfer SOL coin and the second for the rest of the TOKENS. Can be done? does anyone know the command?

Answer (score 1):

The SPL docs contain CLI examples for every possible action with spl-token.  To perform a transfer, you can do:

```
$ spl-token transfer EPjFWdd5AufqSSqeM2qN1xzybapC8G4wEGGkZwyTDt1v <AMOUNT> <RECEIVER>
```

Here, we specify the USDC mint `EPjFWdd5AufqSSqeM2qN1xzybapC8G4wEGGkZwyTDt1v`, which means that the CLI will attempt to send from the default user's associated token account for USDC.

You can see all of the examples for tranfers at https://spl.solana.com/token#example-transferring-tokens-to-another-user